# Why does $map not output an array in case the input array is one in length?

Tags: jsonata

Please check this - https://try.jsonata.org/0L_oYffzT

Here the output of the $map function is not an array.

whereas https://try.jsonata.org/Rf8UI_TMy seems to work fine when the input array is more than 1 in length.

Comment: Are you still having this problem? :) Try to wrap $map function like this. [$map(...)]

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [result structure feature](https://docs.jsonata.org/construction) to accomplish this task:

```js
var json = { "projectIds": [ 1 ] }
var result = jsonata('projectIds[].{"projectId": $}').evaluate(json);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsonata/jsonata.min.js"></script>
```

Using `$map` for this purpose has an [open issue](https://github.com/jsonata-js/jsonata/issues/512) that point to [workarounds only](https://github.com/jsonata-js/jsonata/issues/462#issuecomment-713869797)

Comment: How does this apply to using `map`?

Comment: I missed to point the link to an open issue on `$map`, updated

Comment: Yeah, I know about the open issue. In your case, I always need to add the complete schema to get the map results. Thanks for trying.